# Client specified an invalid argument error from Firebase Auth UI

Tags: google-cloud-platform, firebaseui, identity-aware-proxy

I have appengine application protected by IAP/GCIP using email as external provider.
Using sample angular project for firebase authentication as provided in iap-gcip-web-toolkit github project, I want to use this authentication UI for the appengine application

When I try to access the firebase authentication UI, getting following error

> Client specified an invalid argument

I have ensured that firebase uses the gcp project linked to it and also the API Key associated with firebase/gcp project is used.

Why is this error getting thrown?

Comment: Could you please share a link to code from the repo and the modifications you performed?

Comment: @YeriPelona github project used is: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/iap-gcip-web-toolkit/tree/37af5cc4f80f527a7f5dccf7115c6ad94e4581d1/sample/authui    I used email auth provider as only sign in option and disabled single and multi tenant flow config params.

Comment: Could you please add a [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) from your implementation?

Comment: @YeriPelona Thank You for taking time. I forked the iap-gcip github project to https://github.com/githubtr/iap-gcip-web-toolkit. Followed instructions to enable angular based sample project. No tenants for my gcip project. Email/password is enabled with for project-level IdPs. Only changes are made in firebaseui.component.ts. Deployed to firebase and tried firebase ui directly as well as GCP appengine url. GCP appengine app url is intercetped but getting same error with invalid key.

Comment: Error shown on UI, sometimes is - Invalid project configuration: API key is invalid!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a bad reference of my firebase app associated with gcp project. Uploaded auth ui app to the firebase account associated with gcp project once again and it worked fine